# Odoo 11: How to use different Price accuracy for POS and Purchasing?

Tags: python, odoo-11

I am using unit prices in Purchases with 4 decimal places like 12.1234 LE, but in point of sale I use 2 decimal places like 12.12 LE.

I tried to change "Unit price" and "Account" decimal accuracy to 4 in (Settings\Database Structure\Decimal Accuracy) expected behavior is 12.1234*1000=12123.4 but the line real subtotal was 12120.00 this is because Currency rounding factor is 2 decimal places (Invoicing\Accounting\Currencies\LE).

When I tried to change currency price rounding factor to 4 this causes issues in Point of sales orders payment, as I found a lot of draft payments "Status: NEW" this is because the user in Point of sales enter prices with 2 decimal point which is necessary for ease of usage and for the client view.

I am trying to make a  different Price rounding factor for POS than accounting, is this is the right way? and is there any other ideas?

Comment: Hi, this question doesn't seem to comply with the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section, please read it carefully and create a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to share with the community.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see no one made a comment!! May be my question is not clear enough.

Any way I put this answer for any one who faces same problem, I made a work around, simply I created another currency with Rate=1 with price accuracy= 0.0001 I mean 4 decimal places, then I changed all partner to use this currency by changing (Supplier currency="this new currency").

Then when I make a PO and choose the vendor => currency changes to this currency and decimal places becomes 4 with no issues on POS as it uses the default currency which is 2 decimal places.

By the way this currency does not appear at all in the reports because out of the PO all the payment is automatically with the default currency.